# Merge Database Tables Based on 90 days with dplyr/R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following two database tables:

```
 **PLAN table**:
 customerID    plantype    purchasedate
      1          A          7/16/2004
      1          A           9/1/2005
      2          B          12/3/2014
```

and:

```
**EMAIL table**
customerID  emaildate  openIND opendate
1           2/3/2005      1    2/4/2005
1         10/23/2005      0     NULL
2           1/2/2014      1    1/2/2014
2          1/10/2014      1   1/11/2014
```

What I'm trying to do is create a dataframe in R with dplyr that will calculate the percentage of emails opened for all customers 90 days or less before the purchase date (column C in the Plan table).

I can do this in Excel with a ton of if-statements, vlookups, and manipulation.  I've read many examples of using summarise() and group_by() on this very helpful site, but I'm having trouble actually implementing this in R as these examples are a bit too advanced for my current R skills.

I am able to calculate lifetime percentage of emails opened with these aggregate functions with dplyr, but I'm struggling how to specify a 90-day range, compounded by the fact that 'purchasedate' is different for each row in the large dataset.  My current successful code for the lifetime calculation is below:

```
df2 <-
select(PLAN,customerID,year) %>%
filter(customerID %in% southeast_vector) %>%
arrange(customerID, year) %>%
left_join(EMAIL)%>%
select(customerID, emaildate, year) %>%
group_by(customerID, year) %>%
summarise(lifetimeNumEmails = n(),
      lifetimeNumEmailsOpened = sum(openIND))%>%
mutate(lifetimeEmailOpenPercentage = lifetimeNumEmailsOpened/lifetimeNumEmails)
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance you can provide for how to specify this 90-day range so that I can compute this calculation dynamically in R.  Hopefully in addition to solving my question, this can help those making the initial transition from excel to R and dplyr in their efforts too. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 90 day condition could be implemented as

`dayLookup = 90` and `filter(openIND ==1 & (purchasedate - opendate) >= dayLookup )`

```
require(dplyr)

planDF = read.table(text="customerID    plantype    purchasedate
      1          A          7/16/2004
      1          A           9/1/2005
      2          B          12/3/2014",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,header=TRUE)



planDF$purchasedate = as.Date(planDF$purchasedate  ,format="%m/%d/%Y")
planDF$year = year(planDF$purchasedate)

emailDF = read.table(text="customerID  emaildate  openIND opendate
1           2/3/2005      1    2/4/2005
1         10/23/2005      0     NULL
2           1/2/2014      1    1/2/2014
2          1/10/2014      1   1/11/2014",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,header=TRUE)

emailDF$emaildate = as.Date(emailDF$emaildate  ,format="%m/%d/%Y")
emailDF$opendate = as.Date(emailDF$opendate  ,format="%m/%d/%Y")




#southest_vector was not provided

    outputDF <-
select(planDF,purchasedate,customerID,year) %>%
#filter(customerID %in% southeast_vector) %>%
arrange(customerID, year) %>%
    left_join(emailDF)%>%
        select(customerID,purchasedate,openIND,opendate, emaildate, year) %>%
        group_by(customerID, year) %>%
        filter(openIND ==1 & purchasedate - opendate >= dayLookup ) %>%
        summarise(lifetimeNumEmails_90d = n(),lifetimeNumEmailsOpened_90d = sum(openIND),
        lifetimeEmailOpenPercentage_90d = lifetimeNumEmailsOpened_90d/lifetimeNumEmails_90d) %>% 
        as.data.frame()
```

Please confirm if the output meets your requirements

```
#Output:

#    customerID year lifetimeNumEmails_90d lifetimeNumEmailsOpened_90d lifetimeEmailOpenPercentage_90d
# 1          1 2005                     1                           1                               1
# 2          2 2014                     2                           2                               1
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!